# Why Jsr310Converters convert all Jsr310 types only to java.util.Date

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, java-time

I want to use Java 8 dates in JPA 2.1 entities, but as you know there is no default converters for these types. I have found spring implementation of that converters, but I don't understand implementation.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/convert/Jsr310Converters.java

**Why spring data Jsr310Converters convert all Jsr310 types to java.util.Date?**

**Can I map LocalDate to date type field in my database in that case?**

**Why conversion java.time.LocalDate <==> java.sql.Date isn't better solution to achieve that goal?

https://github.com/marschall/threeten-jpa

In my opinion this solution is better, but I want to know why spring solution is also good

Comment: LocalDate to java.sql.Date is clearly a more sensible conversion. See also https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-63   The JPA implementation I use (DataNucleus) provides mapping to java.sql.Date (as well as many others that this Spring class doesn't seemingly include).